# Averaging the last 7 days in a dataframe based on a specific label against the adjoining column

Tags: python, pandas, average

I'm working with a time series dataframe which shows cumulative positions of a given entity for each hour of the day from 01/06/2022 - 22/08/2022. I'm looking to take the average of the last 7 days which have a specific label against it, which may not necessarily fall on the previous 7 days leading up to the 22/08/2022, see example below:

[image: Example 1]

The labels against the entries can include:

- 5f
- 5i
- 5j
- 5x
- 5h

Each day will have one label against it, with it repeating for each hour in the day. To put it simply, I want to average the most recent 7 days in the 2 month dataframe which has one of these specific labels against it, i.e The average `cumulativeVol` for each hour for the past 7 days where we have had a 5f strategy, or 5i etc.

Expected output of the script should have a DF dimension of [24x1].

I'm wondering can this be achieved solely through Pandas? Or would a tailored method need developed?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this will give the average `cumulativeVols` per labels:

```
last_week = df[df.StartDateTime >= (df.StartDateTime.iloc[-1] - pd.Timedelta(weeks=1))]
last_week.set_index('StartDateTime', inplace=True)
last_week.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='H'), 'Strategy']).cumulativeVols.mean()
```